# php error due to single quotes

Tags: php

i'm getting the php error in the following code due to single quotes.

```
   <?PHP $annoc=echo '<div id="announcement" class="announcement'.$rid1.'">
  <div id="AContent"><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;">'.strip_tags($notify).'</span>                                                   

  <div style="float:right;">
  <span class="remind" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.','Remind')">                   

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Remind me later</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="dont" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.','Dont');"> Don't show me this         

  again</span></div></div></div>';?>
```

plz let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the exact error and where?

Comment: echo doesn't return a value, so you can get rid of `$annoc =`

Comment: In dreamweaver showing the php syntex error.

Comment: You might be better off adding PHP to your HTML, rather than HTML to your PHP. If you understand my meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your single quotes with a `\`

```
    <?PHP $annoc=echo '<div id="announcement" class="announcement'.$rid1.'">
  <div id="AContent"><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;">'.strip_tags($notify).'</span>                                                   

  <div style="float:right;">
  <span class="remind" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.',\'Remind\')">                   

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Remind me later</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="dont" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.',\'Dont\');"> Don\'t show me this         

  again</span></div></div></div>';?>
```

Comment: plz let me know how ?coz i'm using single quotes in starting

Comment: Everytime you want to use a `'` inside the string just escape it like `\'` 

When you need to print a PHP variable (the strings with the $ suffix) then you're going to just use `'` Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting on StackOverflow has got one of them.

```
;"> Don't show again
```

That apostrophe is breaking out of your string. You need to escape it with a . All single quotes that aren't breaking your string need to be escaped e.g.

```
;"> Don\'t show again
```

You also have unescaped single quotes in your onclick variables as Pete has pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have an apostrophe in your

> Don't show me this again

text.  You need to escape that character so that it doesn't think you're terminating the string.  EG:

```
Don\'t show me this again
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a *lot* of HTML, like you do in this case, it's usually simpler to add the PHP to your HTML where appropriate, rather than putting your HTML in a string.

This might be cleaner and help reduce errors in the future:

```
<div id="announcement" class="announcement<?= $rid1 ?>">
<div id="AContent"><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;"><?= strip_tags($notify) ?></span>                                                   

<div style="float:right;">
<span class="remind" onclick="announce(<?= $rid1 ?>,<?= $userID ?>,'Remind')">                   

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Remind me later</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="dont" onclick="announce(<?= $rid1 ?>,<?= $userID ?>,'Dont');"> Don't show me this again</span></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$annoc = echo '<div id="announcement" class="announcement'.$rid1.'">
            <div id="AContent"><span style="margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;">'.strip_tags($notify).'</span>                                                   

            <div style="float:right;">
            <span class="remind" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.',\'Remind\')">                   

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Remind me later</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="dont" onclick="announce('.$rid1.','.$userID.',\'Dont\');"> Don\'t show me this again</span></div></div></div>';
?>
```

That is pretty messed up imo.

Maybe useful for you: If you use double quotes you don't have to make extensive use of quotes.

compare:

```
echo "i speak $myLanguageCount languages";
echo 'i speak '.$myLanguageCount.' languages';
```